# GUI, Java Swing, Labels and Text Fields

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

i recently started learning how to code in Java swing, writing it by hand.
I am trying to make a GUI, for an assignment, but i am struggling to attach four labels to four text fields that are in a Grid format.

The text fields are in a panel, within a panel. So i could have the the fields next to the buttons.

I am really confused on how to go from where i am. As i want each label to go on the left hand side of each text field. So the "Train on" goes on the left hand side next to the text field "On", And the "Train Moving" label goes on the left hand side of the text field "off". And so on. I'm quite a newb at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated thank you. The code i have posted currently works.

*Edit*

Had to remove code for reasons

Comment: This problem looks familiar .... I saw it a few days ago.  Ah yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233473/java-swing-variable-not-incrementing

Comment: When you're designing a label - field form, the [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is an appropriate choice.

Comment: @demongolem Ye i saw this, but he hasn't used any labels or text fields.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc How would you use the GridBagLayout sorry?

Comment: @user3569279, `How would you use the GridBagLayout sorry?` did you read the tutorial on using a GridBagLayout? The tutorial has a working example. What part of the tutorial did you not understand? What problems did you have when you modified the example code?

Comment: @camickr What i then don't understand is how to use the addComponent feature. I think i have confused myself more since i haven't named each text field individually. But if i did that, I'm not too sure how i would get the layout i want.

Comment: @user3569279, naming, or not naming a component has no effect on the layout of the component. The Layout Manager doesn't know or care about the name of a variable. Again the tutorial give a working example. Why would you think our example code would be any different?

Comment: @camickr You seem to think, just looking at example code should be clear to everyone. I'm confused between what i should be using, and how to adapt it to use in my own code. Probably cause I'm not clearly understanding the example.

Comment: @user3569279,  You haven't posted any code that shows what you have attempted to do with the GridBagLayout. You have yet to ask a specific question about the example code. Again, we are not mind readers. We do not know what you do not understand!

Comment: @camickr I'm asking for a understanding, that's possibly put in a different way. When i ask someone how they may use the GridBagLayout, people do it in different ways, in that way i may actually understanding. Or it may become just as confusing. The guy who answered, has actually tried to explain it in his own way, using his own example. I am grateful for his help. You seem to be the only one, who doesn't understand.

Comment: @user3569279, no I understand completely. You made no effort to solve the problem on your own and you asked a question hoping someone would spoon feed you the code. All you had to do was post the code that you attempted to write using the GridBagLayout and someone could hove pointed out the errors. Frankly, the code presented here is far more complicated than is necessary for a simple label/text field pairing of components.

Comment: @camickr No it's asking for help, as i couldn't understand. I don't even know why you are here, if all you want to do is try to cause an argument with people trying to learn. And i have made effort, i have read and tried other solutions. If they don't work, I'm not gonna post them all here. This website is the last line of help, if i can't figure it out myself. Just pointing out the errors isn't really gonna help, when you don't understand why it's an error in the first place. Fortunately there is helpful people out there. "More complicated than is necessary", thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3569279 `And i have made effort` where? All you did was state you didn't understand the tutorial. You didn't state what part. Where did you post the code that you tried and didn't work? The tutorial has 3 button on one row. `How hard would it be to replace the first button with a label, the second button with a text field and then delete the third button?` Then when that works you duplicate that code for the second row. Again `show us you work`. Tell us which line of code you don't understand. Prove to us that you actually did try! That is how you ask a question on the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every realistic example I have of a GridBagLayout is complicated.  This is the simplest, real world example that I have.  This dialog has a GridBagLayout inside of a BoxLayout.  The button is in a JPanel using a FlowLayout

[image: Statistics dialog]

And here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.sudoku.solver.view;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SolutionDialog {

    protected static final Insets   buttonInsets    = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);

    private int                     singleCount;
    private int                     guessCount;

    private long                    elapsedTime;

    private JDialog                 dialog;

    private SudokuFrame             frame;

    public SolutionDialog(SudokuFrame frame, int singleCount, int guessCount,
            long elapsedTime) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.singleCount = singleCount;
        this.guessCount = guessCount;
        this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        dialog = new JDialog(frame.getFrame(), "Statistics");
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel resultsPanel = new JPanel();
        resultsPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        JLabel singleCountLabel = new JLabel("Cells with one possible number:");
        addComponent(resultsPanel, singleCountLabel, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                buttonInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        String s = singleCount + " cells";
        JLabel singleCountString = new JLabel(s);
        addComponent(resultsPanel, singleCountString, 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
                buttonInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel guessCountLabel = new JLabel("Cells where the solver guessed:");
        addComponent(resultsPanel, guessCountLabel, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                buttonInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        s = guessCount + " cells";
        JLabel guessCountString = new JLabel(s);
        addComponent(resultsPanel, guessCountString, 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
                buttonInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel elapsedTimeLabel = new JLabel("Elapsed Time:");
        addComponent(resultsPanel, elapsedTimeLabel, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                buttonInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        s = elapsedTime + " milliseconds";
        JLabel elapsedTimeString = new JLabel(s);
        addComponent(resultsPanel, elapsedTimeString, 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
                buttonInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        mainPanel.add(resultsPanel);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.setAlignmentX(JButton.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(okButton);

        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        dialog.add(mainPanel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setBounds(getBounds());
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets,
            int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    protected Rectangle getBounds() {
        Rectangle f = frame.getBounds();
        Rectangle d = dialog.getBounds();
        d.x = f.x + (f.width - d.width) / 2;
        d.y = f.y + (f.height - d.height) / 2;
        return d;
    }

}
```

In the addComponent method, I create a new GridBagConstraints for each Swing component.  I do this because I don't like remembering defaults.  I prefer to specify all of the constraints for each Swing component.

These Swing components create a JDialog, but the same principles would apply when creating a JPanel.

If you want to see how the whole Swing application fits together, read my article [Sudoku Solver Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196).

Here's another example that's more complicated, but it includes JTextFields.

[image: EnvelopePrinter]

And here's the code to create the entry panel:

```
package com.ggl.envelopes.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.ggl.envelopes.model.Address;
import com.ggl.envelopes.model.EnvelopeModel;
import com.ggl.envelopes.model.State;

public class AddressPanel {

    private static final Insets entryInsets = 
            new Insets(0, 10, 4, 10);
    private static final Insets spaceInsets = 
            new Insets(10, 10, 4, 10);

    private Address currentAddress;

    private AddressComboBoxItemListener listener;

    private DefaultComboBoxModel<Address> addressComboBoxModel;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<State> stateComboBoxModel;

    private EnvelopeModel model;

    private JButton updateButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;

    private JComboBox<Address> addressComboBox;
    private JComboBox<State> stateComboBox;

    private JLabel messageLabel;

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField address1Field;
    private JTextField address2Field;
    private JTextField cityField;
    private JTextField zip5Field;
    private JTextField zip4Field;

    public AddressPanel(EnvelopeModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.listener = new AddressComboBoxItemListener();
        this.addressComboBoxModel = 
                new DefaultComboBoxModel<Address>();
        this.stateComboBoxModel =
                new DefaultComboBoxModel<State>();
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        if (model.getAddresses().size() > 0) {
            gridy = createAddressComboBox(gridy);
        }

        gridy = createAddressControl(gridy);
    }

    private int createAddressComboBox(int gridy) {
        JLabel addressesLabel = new JLabel("Addresses:");
        addressesLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        addComponent(mainPanel, addressesLabel, 0, gridy, 
                1, 1, spaceInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        buildAddressComboBoxModel();

        addressComboBox = new JComboBox<Address>(addressComboBoxModel);
        addressComboBox.addItemListener(listener);
        addComponent(mainPanel, addressComboBox, 1, gridy++, 
                4, 1, spaceInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        return gridy;
    }

    private int createAddressControl(int gridy) {
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        nameLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        addComponent(mainPanel, nameLabel, 0, gridy, 
                1, 1, spaceInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        nameField = new JTextField(30);
        nameLabel.setLabelFor(nameField);
        addComponent(mainPanel, nameField, 1, gridy++, 
                4, 1, spaceInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel address1Label = new JLabel("Address:");
        address1Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        addComponent(mainPanel, address1Label, 0, gridy, 
                1, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        address1Field = new JTextField(30);
        address1Label.setLabelFor(address1Field);
        addComponent(mainPanel, address1Field, 1, gridy++, 
                4, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel address2Label = new JLabel(" ");
        address2Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        addComponent(mainPanel, address2Label, 0, gridy, 
                1, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        address2Field = new JTextField(30);
        address2Label.setLabelFor(address2Field);
        addComponent(mainPanel, address2Field, 1, gridy++, 
                4, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel dummyLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        dummyLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        addComponent(mainPanel, dummyLabel, 0, gridy, 
                1, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        cityField = new JTextField(10);
        dummyLabel.setLabelFor(cityField);
        addComponent(mainPanel, cityField, 1, gridy, 
                1, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        buildStateComboBoxModel();

        stateComboBox = new JComboBox<State>(stateComboBoxModel);
        stateComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (event.getActionCommand()
                        .equals("comboBoxEdited")) {
                    String s = stateComboBox.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString();
                    State t = model.getStateByAbbreviation(s);
                    if (t != null) {
                        stateComboBox.setSelectedItem(t);
                    }
                }
            }   
        });
        stateComboBox.setEditable(true);
        addComponent(mainPanel, stateComboBox, 2, gridy, 
                1, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        zip5Field = new JTextField(6);
        addComponent(mainPanel, zip5Field, 3, gridy, 
                1, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        zip4Field = new JTextField(6);
        addComponent(mainPanel, zip4Field, 4, gridy++, 
                1, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        messageLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        messageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        addComponent(mainPanel, messageLabel, 0, gridy++, 
                5, 1, entryInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JPanel buttonPanel = createButtonPanel();
        addComponent(mainPanel, buttonPanel, 0, gridy++, 
                5, 1, spaceInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        return gridy;
    }

    private void buildAddressComboBoxModel() {
        addressComboBoxModel.removeAllElements();
        for (Address address : model.getAddresses()) {
            addressComboBoxModel.addElement(address);
        }
    }

    private void buildStateComboBoxModel() {
        stateComboBoxModel.removeAllElements();
        for (State state : model.getStates()) {
            stateComboBoxModel.addElement(state);
        }
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3, 20, 0));

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Address");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String message = checkFields();
                if (message.equals("")) {
                    Address address = createAddress();
                    model.addAddress(address);
                    if (model.getAddresses().size() == 1) {
                        mainPanel.removeAll();
                        int gridy = 0;
                        gridy = createAddressComboBox(gridy);
                        gridy = createAddressControl(gridy);
                    } else {
                        clearFields();
                        addressComboBox.removeItemListener(listener);
                        buildAddressComboBoxModel();
                        addressComboBox.addItemListener(listener);
                    }
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    messageLabel.setText("Address \"" + 
                            address.getName() + "\" saved");
                } else {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    messageLabel.setText(message);
                }
            }           
        });
        addButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);

        updateButton = new JButton("Change Address");
        updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String message = checkFields();
                if (message.equals("")) {
                    Address changedAddress = createAddress();
                    updateReturnSenderAddresses(
                            currentAddress, changedAddress);
                    model.updateAddress(
                            currentAddress, changedAddress);
                    clearFields();
                    addressComboBox.removeItemListener(listener);
                    buildAddressComboBoxModel();
                    addressComboBox.addItemListener(listener);
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    messageLabel.setText("Address \"" + 
                            currentAddress.getName() + "\" changed");
                    updateButton.setEnabled(false);
                    deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    messageLabel.setText(message);
                }
            }   
        });
        updateButton.setEnabled(false);
        updateButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        buttonPanel.add(updateButton);

        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete Address");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                deleteReturnSenderAddresses(currentAddress);
                model.removeAddress(currentAddress);
                clearFields();
                addressComboBox.removeItemListener(listener);
                buildAddressComboBoxModel();
                addressComboBox.addItemListener(listener);
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                messageLabel.setText("Address \"" + 
                        currentAddress.getName() + "\" deleted");
                updateButton.setEnabled(false);
                deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
            }   
        });
        deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
        deleteButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);

        return buttonPanel;
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
            Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, 
                fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    private String checkFields() {
        String message = "";

        State state = null;
        try {
            state = (State) stateComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            message = "State abbreviation is invalid";
            return message;
        }

        if (state == null) {
            message = "State abbreviation is null";
            return message;
        }

        String abbreviation = state.getAbbreviation();

        boolean n = nameField.getText().trim().isEmpty();
        boolean a = address1Field.getText().trim().isEmpty();
        boolean c = cityField.getText().trim().isEmpty();
        boolean s = abbreviation.trim().isEmpty();
        boolean z = zip5Field.getText().trim().isEmpty();

        if (n || a || c || s || z) {
            message = "One or more required fields are empty";
            return message;
        }

//      boolean x = stateField.getText().trim().length() > 2;
        boolean g = isNumeric(zip5Field.getText().trim());

//      if (x) {
//          message = "State is more than 2 characters";
//          return message;
//      }

        if (!g) {
            message = "Zip 5 is not numeric";
            return message;
        }

        if (zip4Field.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return message;
        } else {
            if (isNumeric(zip4Field.getText().trim())) {
                return message;
            } else {
                message = "Zip 4 is not numeric";
                return message;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNumeric(String s) {
        try {
            Integer.valueOf(s);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Integer setZip(String s) {
        return (s.isEmpty()) ? null : Integer.valueOf(s);
    }

    private Address createAddress() {
        String abbreviation = 
                ((State) stateComboBox.getSelectedItem())
                .getAbbreviation();

        return new Address(
                nameField.getText().trim(),
                address1Field.getText().trim(),
                address2Field.getText().trim(),
                cityField.getText().trim(),
                abbreviation.toUpperCase(),
                setZip(zip5Field.getText().trim()),
                setZip(zip4Field.getText().trim())
                );
    }

    private void clearFields() {
        nameField.setText("");
        address1Field.setText("");
        address2Field.setText("");
        cityField.setText("");
        stateComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        zip5Field.setText("");
        zip4Field.setText("");
    }

    private void setFields(Address address) {
        nameField.setText(address.getName());
        address1Field.setText(address.getAddressLine1());
        address2Field.setText(address.getAddressLine2());
        cityField.setText(address.getCity());
        stateComboBox.setSelectedItem(
                model.getStateByAbbreviation(address.getState()));
        zip5Field.setText(String.format("%05d", address.getZip5()));
        zip4Field.setText(displayZip4(address.getZip4()));
    }

    private String displayZip4(Integer value) {
        return (value == null) ? "" : String.format("%04d", value);
    }

    private void updateReturnSenderAddresses(Address oldAddress,
            Address newAddress) {
        if (oldAddress.equals(model.getReturnAddress())) {
            model.setReturnAddress(newAddress);
        }
        if (oldAddress.equals(model.getSenderAddress())) {
            model.setSenderAddress(newAddress);
        }
    }

    private void deleteReturnSenderAddresses(Address address) {
        if (address.equals(model.getReturnAddress())) {
            model.clearReturnAddress();
        }
        if (address.equals(model.getSenderAddress())) {
            model.clearSenderAddress();
        }
    }

    public void refresh() {
        messageLabel.setText(" ");
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    public class AddressComboBoxItemListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            currentAddress = (Address) 
                    addressComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            setFields(currentAddress);
            updateButton.setEnabled(true);
            deleteButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

}
```

I used the same addComponent method to add the Swing components to the main JPanel.  You can see how I dealt with the JTextFields.

Comment: Thank you, i think I'm just confusing myself more since i have created four text Fields with no identifier. As i need an identifier to be able to use the addComponent correct? Also i don't know, if i do create the fields individually  i didn't know how to then use the layout manager to get them laid out like a grid, without creating more panels.

Comment: @user3569279: I'm not sure I understand your comments.  Every Swing component has to have a field name so you can add the Swing component to a layout manager.  The field name can be local to the createPartControl method, or global to the class in the case of JTextFields, as you want to get the text in an action listener eventually.

Comment: I don't understand how, when i add a component, how can i differentiate between the different JTextFields.  To add the different labels.

Comment: @user3569279: Give them different field names, as I did in the code example.  I added a picture of the dialog to my answer.  Hopefully, it makes the columns and rows of the GridBagLayout clearer.

Comment: Right, i think i just need to get my head around it. Thank you very much for your help.